# Increment Index for Multiple Sheets in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have an Excel formula which iterates twice over 2 separate columns for different sheets.

Basically it matches two index values for rows and columns of these sheets and stores the two values that are side-by-side (93x16 Matrix).

The formula for doing this is:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$3:$Q$96,MATCH(Formatted!$A3,Sheet1!$A$3:$A$96,0),MATCH(Formatted!$B3,Sheet1!$B$1:$Q$1,0))
```

Where the MASTER sheet is "MATCH" and the sheets go from 1-52.

I want to iterate over all the sheets by copying this formula across 52 columns but I want the sheets to iterate sheet(n+1) times (n=0,1,2,3,.....51)...

How can I iterate this formula or just add 1 to each formula's Sheet value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure to understand your wording here but I guess you are looking for `INDIRECT()` and `COLUMN()` as in following example:

`=INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet"&COLUMN()&"!A1:O24"),RANDBETWEEN(2,24),RANDBETWEEN(2,15))`

[image]

Where `"A1:O24"` is the range for each Sheet(n)
You'll have to adapt the `COLUMN()` criteria depending on where you put the formula (e.g. if you strat in column "B" in sheet Master, you'll have to put `COLUMN()-1`.